# How to optmise code so it doesnt load logo all the time on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a piece of code for sticky header which turns transparent header with white logo on Wordpress Elementor site into white background when scroll position is >=300 and also change the white logo to black logo. i noticed on browser console that it make call to `https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/blacklogo.png` or `https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/whitelogo.png` based on scroll up or down.

how can i optimize below code so that it will make call to logo file only once rather than on every scroll movement

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sticky-header").removeClass('sticky-header');
        
            $(window).on('load scroll', function(){
                //console.log("scrolling");
                var scroll = 300;
                sticky = $('sticky-header').find('.elementor-section');
                //console.log("$(window).scrollTop() "+ $(window).scrollTop());
                //console.log("scroll "+ scroll);
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scroll) 
                {
                    $("#sticky-header").css("background-color","white");
                    $("#rc-logo img").attr("src",'https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/blacklogo.png');
                    $("#rc-logo img").css("width","180px");
                    $("#sticky-header").addClass('sticky-header');
                }
                else 
                {
                    $("#sticky-header").removeClass('sticky-header');
                    $("#sticky-header").css("background-color","transparent");
                    $("#rc-logo img").attr("src",'https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/whitelogo.png');
                    $("#rc-logo img").css("width","180px");
                }
            })
        
    })
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Change it so that the two images get loaded one `display: none` the other `display: block` and toggle visibility each time OR on the server set a good cache time on images served so that it doesn't make a web request just loads from cache

Comment: @Deckerz, good suggestion will work on this as it stop request to logo files.. on each scroll movement

Answer (score 1):

You could move a lot of that to outside JS and put it into CSS instead. Assuming you customise it to look like so. You can do all the styling via the sticky-header class you toggle on and off on the header.

CSS:

```
#sticky-header {
  width: 180px;
}

#sticky-header.sticky-header {
  background-color: white;
}
#sticky-header.sticky-header #black-logo {
  display: block;
}
#sticky-header.sticky-header #white-logo {
  display: none;
}

#sticky-header:not(.sticky-header) {
  background-color: white;
}
#sticky-header:not(.sticky-header) #black-logo {
  display: none;
}
#sticky-header:not(.sticky-header) #white-logo {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sticky-header").removeClass('sticky-header');
    $(window).on('load scroll', function() {
      //console.log("scrolling");
      var scroll = 300;
      //sticky = $('sticky-header').find('.elementor-section');
      //console.log("$(window).scrollTop() "+ $(window).scrollTop());
      //console.log("scroll "+ scroll);
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scroll) {
        $("#sticky-header").addClass('sticky-header');
      } else {
        $("#sticky-header").removeClass('sticky-header');
      }
    })
  })
}(jQuery))
```

HTML:

```
<img id="black-logo" src="https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/blacklogo.png"/>
<img id="white-logo" src="https://domainabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/whitelogo.png"/>
```